# List rotation with limited elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, translate-animation

I have div `container` with list (cards) inside. When I hover it, cards start to moving (`translateX animation`). `container`'s `width` is `300px`, elements count in `container:3`, each element `width:100px`.

So you can see 3 elements in container together `overflow:hidden`. What I want to make?, is that when there is no element to show **translateX animation -100px = 100px** blank space after third element, it start from 1 elements in the list immediately after last, with no blank space.

For now, I have no idea how it could be done without duplicates and etc.

Here is what I have at the moment:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynL2stx2/) (Hover cards to see translation animation)

**UPD 1:**
The code and data (cards count, container size) was taken for example, i'll try to explain better what i want: My goal is to built list of cards and after button was pressed, the list will start moving (like in example with translateX animation) for some time (for example translateX: **12491px**, animation-duration: **15s**;) and stops. But problem is that amount of crads in the list would be in range of 3-40 cards (each card is 100px width & height). So, when i'll set *translateX: **12491px*** for example, it will be out of range and after the last card in the list would appear blank space. I want first and last card to be tied somehow and after the last card immediately appears first card in the list and etc.. Maybe i am searching for solution in a wrong way, but i guess you understand the main idea.

**UPD 2:**
I found that cs:go uses animation that i wanted to write on html\css\js. Here is video: [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cn5laQWRJXY&feature=youtu.be&t=48)

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        3
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.container
{
    width:300px;
        height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.card
{
    float:left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 23px;
}
.cards:hover
{
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    transition-duration: 3s;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: I think you can not achieve that without duplicating first card.

Comment: I guest that you want while the animation runs the first element to appear as a first item and as a last item as well, is that correct?

Comment: @Src it is unclear what you are asking.  Are you saying you want the the first card to appear to be shifting in from the right as it disappears from the left?  If so, then so long as you want a card appearing from one side as it's disappearing from another then it's not possible without duplicating it.  But if you have a fourth card, then *after* the first disappears you can use javascript to move it to the other end of the queue.  That's easy, but it's unclear what you are asking at this point.

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> start from 1 elements in the list immediately after last, with no
>   blank space

This is beyond CSS and you will need Javascript for that. Because, you have tagged the question with Javascript and not jQuery, my answer would be limited to pure Javascript only. Look ma, no JQuery ;)

> I have no idea how it could be done without duplicates

Here is a DIY (*do it yourself*) idea..

1. The main trick is to show at least one item less than the total you have. If you have 3 cards, show only 2. If you have 4 cards, show only 3. Why, because you need to re-position a card when it goes out of view and wrap it back at the end. If you show exactly the same number of cards that you have, then you cannot break half-a-card and wrap it and you will see some blank space until the first one goes out of view. You get the idea?
2. Do not use `translate` or you will end up complicating things for yourself while scripting it out. Keep things simple.
3. Do not use a wrapper for your cards. Why? Because, we will be re-positioning the cards which have gone out of view. When we do that, the next card will take up its place and immediately go out of view making things further difficult for you.
4. To keep things simple, arrange your cards with `absolute` positioning relative to its container. To start with, let all cards stack up at `top:0; and left: 0;`.
5. Next wire-up Javascript to position the `left` property based on the `width` of each card and arrange them linearly.
6. Use `requestAnimationFrame` to control the animation.
7. Keep track of the left-most card and its `left` position. When this goes out of view (*which is 0 minus width*), `appendChild` this card to its container. This will move the card to the end of cards. Also, change the `left` property to it based on the last card in the list.
8. That' all there is to it.

Below is a demo. To make it easy for you to experiment, I have used a settings object to keep the configurable properties which you can easily tweak and see. Look closely at the code and you will find it simple to understand. You can set the `iterations` settings to `0` to make the animation infinite.

Also, note that you do not need to duplicate or fake the cards. Try the demo and add as many cards you want to.

The inline code comments in the snippet, will further help you understand each line of code and relate to the steps above.

**Snippet:**

```js
var list = document.querySelector('.cardList'), // cache the container
    cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card'), // cache the list of cards
    start = document.getElementById('start'),   // buttons
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'), 
    reset = document.getElementById('reset'), 
    raf, init = 0, counter = 0, lastCard, currentIteration = 0, // general purpose variables
    settings = { // settings object to help make things configurable
        'width': 100, 'height': 100, 'speed': 2, 
        'iterations': 2, 'count': cards.length 
    }
;
start.addEventListener('click', startClick); // wire up click event on buttons
stop.addEventListener('click', stopClick);
reset.addEventListener('click', resetClick);
initialize(); // initialize to arrange the cards at start

function initialize() {
    // loop thru all cards and set the left property as per width and index position
    [].forEach.call(cards, function(elem, idx) { 
        elem.style.left = (settings.width * idx) + 'px';
    }); 
    init = -(settings.width); // initialize the view cutoff
    lastCard = cards[settings.count - 1]; // identify the last card
    counter = 0; currentIteration = 0; // reset some counters
    settings.speed = +(document.getElementById('speed').value);
    settings.iterations = +(document.getElementById('iter').value);
}
function startClick() { 
    initialize(); raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(keyframes); // start animating
}
function stopClick() { window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf); } // stop animating
function resetClick() { // stop animating and re-initialize cards to start again
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(raf); 
    document.getElementById('speed').value = '2';
    document.getElementById('iter').value = '2';
    initialize(); 
}

// actual animation function
function keyframes() {
    var currentCard, currentLeft = 0, newLeft = 0;
    // iterate all cards and decrease the left property based on speed
    [].forEach.call(cards, function(elem, idx) {
        elem.style.left = (parseInt(elem.style.left) - settings.speed) + 'px';
    }); 
    currentCard = cards[counter]; // identify left-most card
    currentLeft = parseInt(currentCard.style.left); // get its left position
    if (currentLeft <= init) { // check if it has gone out of view
        // calculate position of last card
        newLeft = parseInt(lastCard.style.left) + settings.width;
        list.appendChild(currentCard); // move the card to end of list
        currentCard.style.left = newLeft + 'px'; // change left position based on last card
        lastCard = currentCard; // set this as the last card for next iteration
        counter = (counter + 1) % settings.count; // set the next card index
        if ((settings.iterations > 0) && (counter >= (settings.count - 1))) { 
            currentIteration++; // check settings for repeat iterations
        }
    }
    if (currentIteration >= settings.iterations) { return; } // when to stop
    raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(keyframes); // request another animation frame
};
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.cardList { 
    position: relative; height: 100px; width: 300px; 
    margin: 10px; border: 2px solid #33e; 
    overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; 
}
.card { 
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; text-align: center;
    height: 100px; width: 100px; line-height: 100px;
    background-color: #99e; 
    font-family: monospace; font-size: 2em; color: #444;
    border-left: 1px solid #33e; border-right: 1px solid #33e;
}

div.controls, button { margin: 10px; padding: 8px; font-family: monospace; }
div.controls input { width: 48px; padding: 2px; text-align: center; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<div class="controls">
    <label>Speed <input id="speed" type="number" min="1" max="8" value="2" />x</label>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <label>Iterations <input id="iter" type="number" min="0" max="8" value="2" /></label>
</div>
<div class="cardList">
    <div class="card">1</div>
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
    <div class="card">4</div>
</div>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/1hkw1v0w/**

***Note:*** I have left out a few things in the demo. Especially, although width and height of the cards is part of the settings object, but currently it left fixed. You can easily use the settings object to make the dimensions of the cards configurable as well.

---

### Edit:

(*as per Op's comment*)

If you want a greater control over distance to scroll, duration and timing-functions (easing), then you could implement those yourself using a library. A couple of such good libraries are the [Robert Penner's Easing Functions](http://robertpenner.com/easing/) and [a jQuery plugin from GSGD](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/). Although you can implement all of that with pure Javascript, it would be easier if you use a library like jQuery.

Catch here is that in order to do so effectively, you must then duplicate the cards. You can do so easily by cloning the entire list a couple of times.

Although you have not tagged this question with jQuery, here is a small demo (*using jQuery to get it done quickly*) where you can configure the speed and the distance.

**Snippet 2:**

```js
var $cardList  = $('.cardList').first(), 
    $cards   = $('.card'), 
    $speed   = $('input[name=speed]'), 
    width   = 100, 
    randomize  = true, 
    distance  = 20 * width 
;

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    $cards.clone().appendTo($cardList);
}

function spin() {
    var newMargin = 0, newDistance = distance, 
        speed = +($speed.filter(':checked').val());
    if (randomize) {
        newDistance = Math.floor(Math.random() * $cards.length * 5);
  newDistance += $cards.length * 5;
        newDistance *= width;
    } 
 newMargin = -(newDistance);
    $cards.first().animate({
        marginLeft: newMargin
    }, speed);
}

$('#spin').click(function() {
    $cards.first().css('margin-left', 0);
    spin();
    return false;
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.cardList { 
    height: 100px; width: 302px; position: relative;
    margin: 10px; border: 1px solid #33e; 
    overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; 
}
.card { 
    display: inline-block; text-align: center;
    height: 100px; width: 100px; line-height: 100px;
    background-color: #99e; 
    font-family: monospace; font-size: 2em; color: #444;
    border-left: 1px solid #33e; border-right: 1px solid #33e;
}
.cardList::before, .cardList::after {
    content: ''; display: block; z-index: 100;
    width: 0px; height: 0px; transform: translateX(-50%);
 border-left: 8px solid transparent;
 border-right: 8px solid transparent;    
}
.cardList::before {
    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 50%;
 border-top: 12px solid #33e;
}
.cardList::after {
    position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 50%;
 border-bottom: 12px solid #33e;
}
div.controls, button { margin: 10px; padding: 8px; font-family: monospace; }
div.controls input { width: 48px; padding: 2px; text-align: center; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
    <label>Speed: </label>
    &nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <label><input name="speed" type="radio" value='6000' />Slow</label>
    <label><input name="speed" type="radio" value='5000' checked />Medium</label>
    <label><input name="speed" type="radio" value='3000' />Fast</label>
</div>
<div class="cardList"><!--
    --><div class="card">1</div><!--
    --><div class="card">2</div><!--
    --><div class="card">3</div><!--
    --><div class="card">4</div><!--
--></div>
<button id="spin">Spin</button>
```

**Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/c50upco5/**

Comment: Nice job. This is very close to what i want to achieve. Can you modify your code to set only distance in pixels that must be traveled and time of this animation (also if it is possible would be grate to set animation-timing-function like in css) instead of Speed and Iterations?

Comment: @Src: In that case it would be prudent to duplicate the cards and use a library. I have added another version using jQuery, also with configurable parameters. Hope that helps you in the right direction. Am confident that with these examples you can learn and work your way as per your need, and take it up from here.

Comment: It is not 100% what i want, but you done good job and gave me some useful stuff to play around. Thank you and here is your +110.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2:**

I wrote a jquery plugin that may act the way you want:

you can add as many cards as you want, right now the "translateX" is random (the script will choose randomly the final card)

[link to the demo](http://ciaccodavi.de/jqslot/)

---

**Update:**

I know, I used duplicates, but now my code works on three cards:

- I added three "fake" cards
- Each "real" card has it's own animation
- the "fake" cards will be overlapped by the real ones once their cycle is finished (*"when there is no element to show"* as you asked)

check the snippet:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.cards {
  width: 600px;
}
.container:hover .card1{
  animation: 1600ms slide1 infinite linear;
}
.container:hover .card2{
  animation: 1600ms slide2 infinite linear;
}
.container:hover .card3{
  animation: 1600ms slide3 infinite linear;
}
.fakecard{z-index:-1000;}
.container:hover .fakecard{
  animation: 1600ms fakeslide infinite linear;
}

@keyframes slide1 {
  0% { transform: translateX(0px); }
  33% { transform: translateX(-100px); }
  33.1% { transform: translateX(+200px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0px); }
}
@keyframes slide2 {
  0% { transform: translateX(0px); }
  66% { transform: translateX(-200px); }
  66.1% { transform: translateX(100px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0px); }
}
@keyframes slide3 {
  0% { transform: translateX(0px); }
  99% { transform: translateX(-300px); }
  99.1% { transform: translateX(+300px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0px); }
}
@keyframes fakeslide {
  0% { transform: translateX(0px); }
  99% { transform: translateX(-300px); }
  99.1% { transform: translateX(+300px); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0px); }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card card1">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="card card2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="card card3">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="card fakecard">
      1 (fake)
    </div>
    <div class="card fakecard">
      2 (fake)
    </div>
    <div class="card fakecard">
      3 (fake)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Previous answer:*

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

I don't think you can do it without duplicates...

If not, can you explain better what you are trying to achieve here?

[snipped code removed]

Comment: In general - this is closer to what i want to achieve. But i want to set for example translateX to 15k on list with 6 elements...

Comment: yeah, I read too late your update... I think a javascript approach could be easier...

Comment: This is the closest verson of what i want to achieve. Look at UPD 2, i found that cs:go game has animation like i wanted

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to modify the dom elements you could take advantage of [flex-item's `order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order);

to do this you'd still need a little JS to add this property after animation has ended;

I also changed to animation instead of transition  so it automatically resets the transform property at the end of animation.

```js
$('.cards').mouseenter(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.card').first().css("order", "2");
  }, 3000);
});

$('.cards').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.card').first().css("order", "-1");
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card {
  float: left;
  /* height: 100px;
    width: 100px;*/
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
.cards:hover {
  animation: trans 3s;
}
/**/

.cards {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 3s;
}
@keyframes trans {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100px)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">1</div>
    <div class="card">2</div>
    <div class="card">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/ynL2stx2/6/)

---

But if you're OK to use JS I suggest you manipulate the order of DOM elements directly,taking the first child element of `.cards` and appending it to the end of list at the end of each animation;

try this:

```js
var anim;

$('.cards').mouseenter(function(){
        
    anim = setInterval(function(){
        $('.cards').append($('.card').first())
    },3000)
     
});

$('.cards').mouseleave(function(){
    clearInterval(anim)                   
});
```

```css
.container{
    width:300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.card{
    float:left;
   /* height: 100px;
    width: 100px;*/
    background-color:blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 23px;
    /**/
    flex:0 0 25%;
}
.cards:hover{
    animation: trans 3s infinite;
}

/**/
.cards{
    width:400px;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
}


@keyframes trans {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100px)
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        3
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

in case you want one card to be present at same time both at the beginning and at the end of card-list you'll need to make a deep-copy / clone of the element;

[here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/ynL2stx2/10/);

Answer (score 2):

[***Here***](http://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/x4f3reja/2/) is the same effect that you mentioned, with a little tweak on your CSS and a helpful hand from jQuery.

### CSS

Change your selector for the `translateX` animation to apply on each of the `.card` boxes when their immediate parent is *hovered*, and not the `.cards` (which is the immediate parent of the `.card`s). This is because you'd want the *cards* to move to the left, and not the *window* through which they appear while making the movement.

That is,

```
.cards:hover .card {   
    transform: translateX(-100px);
    transition-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

### jQuery

```
var $container = $('.container');
var cardWidth = 100;

$container.on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $card0Clone = $('.card').eq(0).clone();    // clone of the first .card element
    $('.cards').append($card0Clone);
    updateWidth();
});
$container.on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $cards = $('.card');
    $cards.eq(0).remove();    // remove the last .card element
});

function updateWidth() {
    $('.cards').width(($('.card').length) * cardWidth);  // no of cards in the queue times the width of each card would result in a container fit enough for all of them
}
```

***Code Explained***

As you move in the mouse pointer, a *clone* of the first card is created, and appended to the end of the cards collection. Further, as you move the mouse out of the hover area, the original `.card` (*which was cloned earlier*) will be removed from the head of the queue - hence, producing a cyclic effect.

The real trick though is with the `updateWidth` function. Every time the mouse enters the `.container` the width of the `.card`s' immediate parent (i.e. `.cards` div) is updated, so that `.cards` div is wide enough to fit in all the `.card`s, and therefore, making sure that each of the *cards* push against each other and stay in one line at the time the *translation* animation is being done.

Comment: It is not quite what i want. Please, read UPD 1. translateX can be grater than 10k

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple technique that manipulates the Dom to create your desired effect

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('.cards').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
if (e.clientX < (this.offsetWidth >> 1)) {
    this.appendChild(this.removeChild(this.firstElementChild));
} else {
    this.insertBefore(this.lastElementChild, this.firstElementChild);
}});
```

then in you css use the `nth-of-type` selector to position elements as required.
Here is your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynL2stx2/14/)

If you are using mouseover you might need to wait for transitionend event before firing again.

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ynL2stx2/13/)

Here I used JQuery, you can configure your animation using two variables

```
var translateX = 1000; //adjust the whole distance to translate
var stepSpeed = 100;   //adjust the speed of each step transition in milliseconds
```

After setting your variables, on the click event of the cards do the following:-

1. Get the number of the steps required based on translateX
2. Loop for the number of steps
3. Inside each loop (each step) move the cards 1 step to the left, then put the first card to the end of the cards to form the connected loop, then return back the cards to it's initial position

Here is the code:

```
var stepsNumber = translateX/100;
for(var i=0; i< stepsNumber; i++)
{
    $('.cards').animate({'left' : -100}, stepSpeed,function(){
         $('.cards div:last').after($('.cards div:first'));
         $('.cards').css({'left' : '0px'}); 
     });
}
```